# In p5js instance mode for several canvases p5 object is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, instance, p5.js, mode

I am running a p5.js sketch on a flask server.
I want to draw several canvases, so i instanced my code like Daniel Schiffman showed in his ["9.11: Instance Mode (aka "namespacing") - p5.js Tutorial"-Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Su792jEauZg), but when i run the code it gives me **"Uncaught ReferenceError: p5 is not defined"** on the line i instantiate my canvas

```
var drawCanvas = new p5(firstcanvas);
```

When i run the code in the p5 web editor it works.

The script tag in my html looks like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.js"
       integrity="sha512-a5hlZKgpC1LVAuKgVeXdP0D9Yfacj0hLtNdzx9zFMkIWRrQyO37KtIPiqArGmVuaBYu3ON6Vt0N3+G/JaLXQYQ=="
       crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

so thats the newest version. any idea? thanks

Minimal reproducive example:

```js
var firstCanvas = function(a) {
  let abc;
  a.setup = function() {
    abc = 100;
    a.createCanvas(800, 600);
    a.background(260);
    n = a.createButton("NEW");
    n.position(20, a.height + 225);
    n.mousePressed(clearCanvas);
  }
  a.draw = function() {
    a.fill(10);
    a.rect(a.mouseX, a.mouseY, abc, 50);
  }

  function clearCanvas() {
    a.background(260);
  }
}
var drawCanvas = new p5(firstCanvas);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.js"
       integrity="sha512-a5hlZKgpC1LVAuKgVeXdP0D9Yfacj0hLtNdzx9zFMkIWRrQyO37KtIPiqArGmVuaBYu3ON6Vt0N3+G/JaLXQYQ=="
       crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a minimal reproducible example of your issue https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine when I copy that script tag and define a simple `firstcanvas` function.

```js
function firstcanvas(p5) {
  var x;

  p5.setup = function() {
    p5.createCanvas(400, 400);
    p5.background(51);
    x = p5.width/2;
  }
  
  p5.draw = function() {
    p5.background(51);
    p5.circle(x, p5.height/2, 100);
    x++;
    if (x - 50 >= p5.width) x = -50;
  }
}

var drawCanvas = new p5(firstcanvas);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.js"
       integrity="sha512-a5hlZKgpC1LVAuKgVeXdP0D9Yfacj0hLtNdzx9zFMkIWRrQyO37KtIPiqArGmVuaBYu3ON6Vt0N3+G/JaLXQYQ=="
       crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
I did run the html file direct without debugging in PyCharm and got this error.
When i gave it a route and started it over the run.py it worked (almost) as it should.